# Azure Webjob Unable Start Due to Binding Error

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, webjob

I have a webjob that is supposed to read from an Azure queue and do something with the payload found. The issue I'm having is the webjob won't start and here is the error

*[02/17/2021 15:40:11 > e80592: INFO] [15:40:10 ERR] Error indexing method 'Functions.ProcessStudentPerfQueueMessages'
[02/17/2021 15:40:11 > e80592: INFO] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexingException: Error indexing method 'Functions.ProcessStudentPerfQueueMessages'
[02/17/2021 15:40:11 > e80592: INFO]  ---> System.InvalidOperationException: **Can't bind parameter 'message' to type 'StudentMessage'.**
[02/17/2021 15:40:11 > e80592: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.Data.ClassDataBindingProvider`1.TryCreateAsync(BindingProviderContext context) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Bindings\Data\ClassDataBindingProvider.cs:line 35
[02/17/2021 15:40:11 > e80592: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.Data.DataBindingProvider.TryCreateAsync(BindingProviderContext context) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Bindings\Data\DataBindingProvider.cs:line 41
[02/17/2021 15:40:11 > e80592: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.CompositeBindingProvider.TryCreateAsync(BindingProviderContext context) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Bindings\BindingProviders\CompositeBindingProvider.cs:line 23
[02/17/2021 15:40:11 > e80592: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexer.IndexMethodAsyncCore(MethodInfo method, IFunctionIndexCollector index, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Indexers\FunctionIndexer.cs:line 196
[02/17/2021 15:40:11 > e80592: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexer.IndexMethodAsync(MethodInfo method, IFunctionIndexCollector index, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Indexers\FunctionIndexer.cs:line 149
[02/17/2021 15:40:11 > e80592: INFO]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[02/17/2021 15:40:11 > e80592: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexer.IndexMethodAsync(MethodInfo method, IFunctionIndexCollector index, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Indexers\FunctionIndexer.cs:line 157
[02/17/2021 15:40:11 > e80592: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexer.IndexTypeAsync(Type type, IFunctionIndexCollector index, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Indexers\FunctionIndexer.cs:line 85
[02/17/2021 15:40:13 > e80592: INFO] [15:40:13 FTL] Web Job start-up failed*

Here is the code

```
public class Functions
{
    private readonly IService _service;
    public Functions(IService service)
    {
         _service = service;
    }
    public async Task ProcessStudentPerfQueueMessages([QueueTrigger("studentperf")] StudentMessage message)
    {
         await new StudentPerfQueueProcessor(_pascoService).ProcessMessage(message));
     }
```

There aren't any messages in the queue at the moment.
If I change `StudentMessage` to a `string` then the webjob starts successfully in Azure. This is a Net Core Webjob. Please help.

Comment: How do you define the `StudentMessage` class？Check this first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp#usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the student class

```
public class StudentMessage
{
   public int StudentId { get; set; }
   public int SubjectId { get; set; }
   public StudentForm Form { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<int, AnswerStatus> QuestionAnswerStatus { get; set; }
   public string Message { get; set; }
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Doris Lv got me thinking about the `StudentMessage` class. I decided to comment out the `Message` property in the StudentMessage and bam!! It started successfully. Must be something with the Newtonsoft.json.

Comment: Why would you mark your answer? Your answer is completely a copy of Doris's answer.

Comment: If other users answer useful to you, they can get some points if you accept it. In this way, more high-scoring users will help you solve technical problems. You always ask and answer yourself, which is not a good behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As the Azure Function's [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp#usage) described:

> Access the message data by using a method parameter such as string
> paramName. You can bind to any of the following types:
>
> - Object - The Functions runtime deserializes a JSON payload into an
>   instance of an arbitrary class defined in your code.
> - string
> - byte[]
> - CloudQueueMessage

Not sure how you define the `StudentMessage` class, but if you could meet your need by using `string` type, you could consider use it.